# Are these linear maps bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_c$ be the complex vector space of $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ functions with compact support in $(0,1)$.Define two norms on it , $\|x(t)\|_u=\text{max}_{t\in (0,1)} \ |x(t)|$ and $\|x(t)\|_d=\text{max}_{t\in (0,1)}\ |x'(t)|$ denoted by $X_u$ and $X_d$ respectively and $T(x)=x'(t)$. Are the following maps bounded? $$a)\ T:X_u\to X_u \\ b)\ T:X_u \to X_d$$

Answer (score 1):

The question is essentially asking the following:

Suppose you have a $C_c^\infty(0,1)$ function $x(t)$.

a) $(Tx)(t) = x'(t)$. Can the derivative of $x$ be controlled by bounding $x$?

> Hint: the other direction works: if you can bound $x'$, then you can use the fundamental theorem of calculus to control $x$. Should we expect the converse to hold? If we keep $x(t)$ bounded by $1$, how bad can we make the behavior of $x'(t)$?

b) Can the second derivative of $x$ be controlled by bounding $x$? If you know the answer to a) then this question should be trivial.

Comment: Yes, I would like to see an example of a sequence of $f_n$ with $\|f_n\|_\infty \le 1$ and $\|f_n'\|_\infty$ unbounded. Because that's what I've been trying to construct for the past 30 minutes but have not managed. I believe this is what's difficult about this exercise.

Comment: @Rudy Overgenerous hint: take an oscillating function, then increase its frequency without changing its amplitude.

Comment: What's an example of an oscillating function with compact support?

Comment: $0$ on $(0,\epsilon)$ and $(\epsilon + a, 1)$, with $0 < \epsilon < \epsilon + a < 1$, and like a sine function on $[\epsilon,\epsilon + a]$, with some translation and smoothing at the endpoints (via, say, convolution with an approximate identity) to make things $C^\infty$. Finding an explicit example in closed form is bound to be annoying, and not the point of the exercise.

Comment: I think is clear that the idea of the exercise is to give an explicit example.

Comment: Seriously: first you pretend you can solve the exercise by "giving" "overgenerous hints" and when I press you for an answer you admit you can't solve it either.

Comment: Far from it - this description is as explicit as you need. I've prescribed a way to come up with an explicit sequence, and one could in principle write it down in closed form, if one were to choose the approximate identity and the initial piecewise continuous form of the solution, but at the very least one could use convolution and leave it in integral form. I don't see how much more explicit this needs to be. And you could do with being a lot less combative in your comments, it's not at all constructive.

Comment: Also, you are clearly not familiar with the idea of a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet if a picture of such an example did not immediately come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Edit 2:let $[a,b]\subset(0,1)$.let $g(x)=1$ on$[a,b]$ and $g(x)=0$ on $(0,a-\epsilon)\cup(b+\epsilon,1)$. By "using" proper translation and rescaling of $e^{-1/(x^2-1)}$ defined on $[a-\epsilon,a]$ and $[b,b+\epsilon]$ we can turn $g$ into a function in $C^\infty_c(0,1)$ that has norm less than one. Buy its derivative has rather large norm.by making $\epsilon$ smaller we are not changing the norm of the function however since the two gaps meaning $[b,b+\epsilon]$ and $[a-\epsilon,a]$are getting narrower then derivatives evaluated at the endpoints becomes larger. [here](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%5Be%5E%7B-1%2F%28x%5E2-1%29%7D%2C%7Bx%2C-1%2C1%7D%5D&x=-988&y=-71)